# How to use object with variable in react native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I am new in react native.

My question is pretty simple:
I need to change subject of email with a address of consultant.
[example: Vul uw vraag, naam en adres in{address}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iURp.jpg)

Address is object, so how to make a strings from this :
{activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.street} {activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.houseNumber}{activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.postCode} {activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.city}
and to make with one variable which I will use in subject and body also.
Thank you all :)

```
    const onSendMail = () => {
    Linking.openURL(
        `mailto:${activeUser.rentalUnit?.complex?.email || 'info@woonzorg.nl'}?subject=${Strings.Board.EmailSubject}&body=${Strings.Board.EmailText} ${
            activeUser.rentalUnit?.address?.street
        }  `,
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you wanna concatenation the address string?

```
const onSendMail = () => {
 const subjectAddress = `${activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.street} ${activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.houseNumber}${activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.postCode} ${activeUser.rentalUnit?.address.city}`
    Linking.openURL(
        `mailto:${activeUser.rentalUnit?.complex?.email || 'info@woonzorg.nl'}?subject=${subjectAddress}&body=${Strings.Board.EmailText} ${
            subjectAddress
        }  `,
    );
};
```